# Laravel Diagram Generator

Tags: laravel

I am facing a problem dealing with Laravel database and model.

I am working on an existing laravel project with contains only models (no migrations)

I wanted to generate a database from models but till now I could not find any solution, so I thought of diagram generator in Laravel to help me generate the tables of the database so I could know the columns of the tables but I did it work. 
when I tap the command : `php artisan generate:erd`  it won't work.

The error is:

> "There are no commands defined in the "generate" namespace."

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you cannot directly use this command `php artisan generate:erd` 
you have not install package that's why you got this error:

> There are no commands defined in the "generate" namespace.

---

First You need to install [Laravel ER Diagram Generator](https://github.com/beyondcode/laravel-er-diagram-generator) package via composer:

```
composer require beyondcode/laravel-er-diagram-generator --dev
```

Then after you can generate entity relation diagrams using the provided artisan command:`php artisan generate:erd` This will generate a file called `graph.png.`

Comment: I also developed a similar package for Laravel, but my package generates the diagram based on the database, not on models. Behind the scenes it uses SchemaCrawler. If interested check it out here: https://github.com/daniel-werner/laravel-schemacrawler/